# Getting Unable to determine application identity of the caller Error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to store and retrieve data in Isolated storage mode in a winforms application. I have followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz.aspx) msdn article and this is the code

```
  IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Machine | IsolatedStorageScope.Application,null,null);
```

When I exceute the above code I am getting **Unable to determine application identity of the caller** error.

Could anyone help me too solve this issue ?

Regards

Ramalingam S

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294461/unable-to-determine-application-identity-of-the-caller

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question as this one is WinForms (the other is Silverlight) and the cause is different.

Answer (score 7):

In a WinForms application, `GetMachineStoreForApplication()` or `IsolatedStorageScope.Application` do not work. The application speciifc storages are designed for ClickOnce applications only.

Instead, use `GetMachineStoreForAssembly()` or `IsolatedStorageScope.User` if you want to store settings on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 5):

Many examples from MSDN for Isolated storage appear incomplete.

You want to call these instead of `GetStore`:

- GetMachineStoreForApplication()
- GetMachineStoreForAssembly()
- GetMachineStoreForDomain()

Answer (score 4):

Please use this:

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null)
```

Comment: Funny enough, I was using almost identical overload, but with single `null` parameter at the end: `IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null)`, which worked in the past, but broke recently (guessing the reason is Windows update). Overload you provided, with 2 `null` parameters fixed the problem. :O